# Can we use executor framework and parallel stream together?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

> I am having List of String to post through Rest api, not sure whether below code is correct performance-wise ??

```
ExecutorService exService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
    reqList.parallelStream().forEach(reqId->exService.execute(new ReqRunnable(reqId)));
    exService.shutdown();
    try {
        exService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }catch(InterruptedException ee) {
         LOGGER.warn(String.format("Thread %s has been interuptted %s ",Thread.currentThread().getName(),ee));
            // Restore interrupted state...
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    }
```

Rest code

```
   public class ReqRunnable implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger LOGGER=LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReqRunnable.class);
        String reqId;
         ReqRunnable(String reqId)
        {
            this.reqId=reqId;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LOGGER.info(String.format("Thread -%s and reqId - %s",Thread.currentThread().getName(),reqId)); 
            IRSUpdateService.executeRequest(reqId);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: @ Nikolas thanks would like to share your thought ?? what can be better done here

Comment: I take a look tomorrow.

Comment: The `parallelStream` is unlikely to give you anything, all this code does, is iterating the list and adding the elements to the executor's queue. Doing this in parallel, will only create overhead for no benefit. If you want to simplify the code, change the `ReqRunnable` to implement `Callable<Void>` instead of `Runnable`. Then, you can do a single `exService.invokeAll(reqList.stream() .map(ReqRunnable::new) .collect(Collectors.toList()));` which will return when all jobs have been executed.